# Sending an event when window.location.href changes

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, js

**My setup:**
I have a LWC which is placed in Shared Footer, so I don't have to add it manually on every page. This component is responsible only for sending events.

**What problems do I have:**
I need to do this so that every time *window.location.href* changes, this event is sent. Before, I was sending event on connectedCallback, but sometimes connectedCallback doesn't trigger, I also tried renderedCallback, but also it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried adding an event listener ? for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes) on stackoverflow might give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution, creating a wired method on CurrentPageReference worked like a charm.

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

@wire(CurrentPageReference)
method(data) {
  doSomethingWithData(data)
};
```